# How can I set compatibility mode for Amazon OpenSearch using CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticsearch, opensearch

Since AWS has replaced ElasticSearch with OpenSearch, some clients have issues connecting to the OpenSearch Service.

To avoid that, we can enable compatibility mode during the cluster creation.

> Certain Elasticsearch OSS clients, such as Logstash, check the cluster
> version before connecting. Compatibility mode sets OpenSearch to
> report its version as 7.10 so that these clients continue to work with
> the service.

I'm trying to use CloudFormation to create a cluster using *AWS::OpenSearchService::Domain* instead of *AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain* but I can't see a way to enable compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AWS::OpenSearchService::Domain`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opensearchservice-domain.html) CloudFormation resource has a property called [`AdvancedOptions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opensearchservice-domain.html#cfn-opensearchservice-domain-advancedoptions).

As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/rename.html#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20compatibility%20mode%20using%20the%20configuration%20API%2C%20set%20override_main_response_version%20to%20true%3A), you should pass `override_main_response_version` to the advanced options to enable compatibility mode.

Example:

```yaml
Resources:
  OpenSearchServiceDomain:
    Type: AWS::OpenSearchService::Domain
    Properties:
      DomainName: 'test'
      EngineVersion: 'OpenSearch_1.0'
      AdvancedOptions:
        override_main_response_version: true
```

Answer (score 4):

To do this in terraform use the config

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "search" {
  domain_name = "search"

  advanced_options = {
    "override_main_response_version" = "true"
  }
}
```

docs can be found can be found here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticsearch_domain

Answer (score 2):

You can add this in the advanced section tab AdvancedOptions.

Example:

Resources:
OpenSearchServiceDomain:
Type: AWS::OpenSearchService::Domain
Properties:
AdvancedOptions:
override_main_response_version: true

Comment: AdvancedOptions:
      override_main_response_version: true is working

Comment: thanks , looks like this is new